# Keep the language between controllers (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net, cookies, localization, internationalization, asp.net-core-1.1

I have build a multilingual site in ASP.NET Core. I am newbie in this field, so maybe I did something incorrect, but switching the language does not keep its value between controllers...

Say, in the `HomeController` I have the following

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
        new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
    );

    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

By default the application is in, say, French.

In order to change the language I have a link that does `+"?culture=en"`, like
http://localhost:23404/?culture=en

The problem is that when I change the page, say, I navigate to `http://localhost:23404/Home/Admin` the language is reset to the default french... so I need to do `http://localhost:23404/Home/Admin?culture=en` in order to change the language again.

I recuperate the language in a view, by eg, like this:

```
string lang = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>()
              .RequestCulture.UICulture.Name.ToLower();
```

Comment: I'd try to add the language as part for the URL routing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit, I am a newbie in this field of asp.net mvc localization, and probably I don't know how to integrate the cookie in the "default" route...